# Concatenating list items with string

Tags: python

I'm taking a list generated from reading a file and trying to take each item and concatenating it to another input string. I can understand the error; I can't concat a list item with a string. But how do I convert each item from the list into a string. I tried `' '.join(list)` but that didn't work either.

I'm getting the following error:

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./attack2.py", line 40, in <module>
    print subcheck(returned_list, ['--domain'])
  File "./attack2.py", line 31, in subcheck
    socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Basic Domain bruteforcer

Usage:
  attack2.py (-f <file>) (-d <domain>) [-t 10] [-v]
  attack2.py -h | --help

Arguments:
  -f --file File to read potential Sub-domains from. (Required)
  -d --domain Domain to bruteforce. (Required)
Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -p --proxy    Proxy address and port. [default: http://127.0.0.1:8080] (Optional)
  -t --thread   Thread count. (Optional)
  -v --verbose  Turn debug on. (Optional)
"""
import socket
from docopt import docopt


def fread(dwords):
        flist = open(dwords).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '.') for s in flist]

def subcheck(subdomain, domain):
        for sub in subdomain:
                socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)
        return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
        print arguments
        print fread(arguments['--file'])
        returned_list = fread(arguments['--file'])
        print subcheck(returned_list, ['--domain'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print subcheck(returned_list, ['--domain'])
```

Did you mean to retrieve the domain option from the arguments object?

```
print subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'])
```

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean. Im trying to take the values from the list (example: admin.) and contact them to a domain name passed via the domain argument, then ill do a `socket.gethostbyname` to check if the concated list item and domain are valid. hope that makes sense

Comment: Ok. But to actually pass the domain name in to the `subcheck` function, you have to get it out of `arguments`. If you just give `['--domain']` to it, it won't know what the user specified.

Comment: arr ic, ok so i have 2 issues. thanks for pointing that out. im now getting it out of arguments and getting the following error `
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./attack2.py", line 40, in <module>
    print subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'])
  File "./attack2.py", line 31, in subcheck
    socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` so if im understanding that correctly i need to loop each item in the subcheck function?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. I don't know much about the `socket` module. It may be worthwhile to make a new question for that error.